# Construction of continuous measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

What additional axioms do I have to assume in order to make the set-fucntion in the following definition continuous (and convex)?

**Non-additive measure** Let $\left(X, \mathcal{F} \right)$ be a measurable space. We then call a set-function $\mu$ a non-additive measure
$$\mu_{s}: \mathcal{F} \to [0,+\infty)$$
iff it satisfies following properties:

1. (boundary conditions) $\mu (\{\emptyset\}) = 0$ and $\mu(X) < +\infty$
2. (monotonicity)  $A_1,A_2 \in \mathcal{F}: A_1 \subset A_2  \Rightarrow \mu (A_1) \leq \mu (A_2)$

Comment: What do you mean by "continuous," precisely?

Comment: Obviously the axiom "being continuous" is sufficient. You might want to be more specific.

Comment: Do you mean I should provide the convergence and continuity definitions for set-functions?